# Enable / Disable button depending on two inputs

Tags: javascript

I have two inputs i want if one of them is equal to the other the button will be enabled else it's disabled.

I managed to do it in Ajax, but i need to do it in Javascript

```
$(':password').keyup(function() {
    if($('#pass').val() == $('#pass1').val() && $('#pass').val()!=='') {
       $('#go').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
       $('#go').attr('disabled', true);   
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between AJAX and Javascript from your point of view?

Comment: I don't need to do something like this on a server side

Comment: you have a node.js server?

Comment: I just need to compare two inputs and enable a button depending on input

Comment: Why doesn't the solution you have work? I don't see any server-side calls

Comment: @fjc i just want a function in pure Javascript to compare to input and enable a button if they are the same unless disable it.

Comment: And what is the problem with the given code? Why don't you want to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `form validation` functionality.
There are a lot of plugins and libs for this kind of task.

but there is a simple example

```js
function getElements(){
 return {
  password: document.querySelector('input[name="password"]'),
  confirm: document.querySelector('input[name="passwordConfirm"]'),
  button: document.querySelector('button'),
 }
}

function validate(){
 let els = getElements();
 els.button.disabled = els.password.value !== els.confirm.value;
}

let elements = getElements();
elements.password.addEventListener('input', validate);
elements.confirm.addEventListener('input', validate);
validate();
```

```html
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password...">
<input name="passwordConfirm" type="password" placeholder="password confirm...">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

and jQuery variant

```js
function validate(event){
 let $frm = $(event.target).closest('form');
 let pas = $frm.find('input[name="password"]');
 let conf = $frm.find('input[name="passwordConfirm"]');
 let btn = $frm.find('button');
 btn.prop('disabled', pas.val() !== conf.val());
}

let $frm = $('form');
$frm.on('input', validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password...">
<input name="passwordConfirm" type="password" placeholder="password confirm...">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's your script "translated" to vanilla JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector(':password').addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  if (document.querySelector('#pass').value == document.querySelector('#pass1').value && document.querySelector('#pass').value !== '') {
    document.querySelector('#go').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#go').disabled = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a JSFiddle for you, implementing that functionality in plain JS: https://jsfiddle.net/3m9g4p0h/4/

JS:

```
var pw1 = document.getElementById('pw1');
var pw2 = document.getElementById('pw2');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
function compare() {
    button.disabled = pw1.value !== pw2.value || pw1 === '';
}
pw1.addEventListener('keyup', compare);
pw2.addEventListener('keyup', compare);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="password" id="pw1" />
<input type="password" id="pw2" />
<button id="button" disabled="true">
  Click me
</button>
```